# Open an activity from a Listview undetermined number of items

Tags: android, listview, numbers, undefined, items

another question. Ok so I have a sax Parser for an android app, the parser obtains data from a website(title, url, data, etc...)(and I don't know how many items I'm getting from the website) so with the data obtained I  created a listview, every item in the listview opens an URL, I know how to open a webview from a listview when I know the exact numbers of items in my ListView, but in this case I don't know how many items I'm getting. So my question is how do I open a new activity(my webview) from a listview without knowing how many items I received from a website?

Comment: if you use arraylist then check arraylist size

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Never Ending ListView`](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/) and get it working. You will probably `adapter.getCount()` from the Adapter that will give you the number of Items in the ListView.